# Why is Boost's QuickSort slower compared to Julia's QuickSort?

Tags: c++, performance, julia, benchmarking, quicksort

I am comparing the performance between Julia and C++. Then I found quick sort is much faster in Julia (and even faster than C++), especially when the size of array is very big.

Can anyone explain the reasons?

**quickSort.jl**

```
include("../dimension.jl")
function execute()  
    n = getDimension()
    print(stderr, "Julia,quickSort_optim,$n,");  # use default delimiter
    arr = zeros(Int32, n)
    for i = 1:n
        arr[i] = (777*(i-1)) % 10000
    end
    if n > 0
        sort!(arr; alg=QuickSort)
    end
end

# executing ...
execute()
```

**quickSort_boost.cpp**

```
#include "dimension.h" 
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/sort/pdqsort/pdqsort.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
 
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::sort; 

int main()
{
    int n = getDimension();
    cerr << "C++,quickSort_boost," << n << ",";
    
    vector<int> arr(n);
    unsigned long long w;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){  // array for sorting
        w = (777*i) % 10000; // Array with values between 0 and 10000
        arr[i] = w;
    }
    
    if (n > 0){
        pdqsort_branchless(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](const int &a, const int &b){return ( a < b );});
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Comparison**

[image: Performance chart plotting size of array vs runtime]

**Note**

The function getDimension() is used to get the array size.

The execution time is measured with the shell command: /usr/bin/time under Ubuntu. Compiler: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2. Optimization level: -02. CPU: Intel i7-3820QM

The reason that I compared the whole execution time rather than just the algorithm itself is because I want to compare the performance between these two languages, which simulates a real application scenario.

In Julia official document, it writes: QuickSort: good performance for large collections.
Is this because Julia uses a special implementation inside the algorithm.

**More samples**

I run the test with more samples. It seems that **the distribution of the data is the issue.**

1. best case with broadly distributed data:

```
function execute()  # julia code segment for specifying data
    for i = 1:n
        arr[i] = i
    end

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){  // c++ boost code segment for specifying data
    arr[i] =  i + 1; 
}
```

[image: QuickSort-best case with broadly distruted data]

2. worst case with broadly distributed data:

```
function execute()  # julia code segment for specifying data
    for i = 1:n
        arr[i] = n - i + 1
    end

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){  // c++ boost code segment for specifying data
    arr[i] =  n - i;  
}
```

[image: QuickSort-worst case with broadly distruted data]

3. Concentrated distributed data

```
function execute()  # julia code segment for specifying data
    for i = 1:n
        arr[i] = i % 10
    end

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){  // c++ boost code segment for specifying data
    arr[i] =  (i + 1) % 10;  
}
```

[image: Concentrated distributed data]

[My source code](https://github.com/David1231123/quickSort-bechmark-in-Julia-and-C-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217968/discussion-on-question-by-david-why-is-boosts-quicksort-slower-compared-to-juli).

Answer (score 11):

Not sure what's up with the timings – you don't include enough code to test or reproduce. The Julia code for QuickSort is pretty simple, you can see the source for it here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/77487611fd9751c0f31ac3853072e6ca11efaf05/base/sort.jl#L518-L579

I'll include the code for easy reading here as well:

```
@inline function selectpivot!(v::AbstractVector, lo::Integer, hi::Integer, o::Ordering)
    @inbounds begin
        mi = midpoint(lo, hi)

        # sort v[mi] <= v[lo] <= v[hi] such that the pivot is immediately in place
        if lt(o, v[lo], v[mi])
            v[mi], v[lo] = v[lo], v[mi]
        end

        if lt(o, v[hi], v[lo])
            if lt(o, v[hi], v[mi])
                v[hi], v[lo], v[mi] = v[lo], v[mi], v[hi]
            else
                v[hi], v[lo] = v[lo], v[hi]
            end
        end

        # return the pivot
        return v[lo]
    end
end

function partition!(v::AbstractVector, lo::Integer, hi::Integer, o::Ordering)
    pivot = selectpivot!(v, lo, hi, o)
    # pivot == v[lo], v[hi] > pivot
    i, j = lo, hi
    @inbounds while true
        i += 1; j -= 1
        while lt(o, v[i], pivot); i += 1; end;
        while lt(o, pivot, v[j]); j -= 1; end;
        i >= j && break
        v[i], v[j] = v[j], v[i]
    end
    v[j], v[lo] = pivot, v[j]

    # v[j] == pivot
    # v[k] >= pivot for k > j
    # v[i] <= pivot for i < j
    return j
end

function sort!(v::AbstractVector, lo::Integer, hi::Integer, a::QuickSortAlg, o::Ordering)
    @inbounds while lo < hi
        hi-lo <= SMALL_THRESHOLD && return sort!(v, lo, hi, SMALL_ALGORITHM, o)
        j = partition!(v, lo, hi, o)
        if j-lo < hi-j
            # recurse on the smaller chunk
            # this is necessary to preserve O(log(n))
            # stack space in the worst case (rather than O(n))
            lo < (j-1) && sort!(v, lo, j-1, a, o)
            lo = j+1
        else
            j+1 < hi && sort!(v, j+1, hi, a, o)
            hi = j-1
        end
    end
    return v
end
```

Nothing special going on there, just a basic well-optimized quicksort. So the real question is why the C++/Boost version is slow, which I'm not in a good position to answer. Perhaps one of the many C++ experts hanging around here can address that.

It seems like it's possible that C++ does not choose pivots as well as Julia does. Pivot selection is a bit of a balancing act: on the one hand, if you pick bad pivots the asymptotic behavior can become really bad; on the other hand, if you spend too much time and effort picking pivots, it can slow the whole sort down considerably.

Another possibility is that Boost's quicksort implementation doesn't use a different algorithm as a base case once the array size gets smaller. That is pretty key for good performance since quicksort doesn't perform well on small arrays. The Julia version switches to insertion sort for arrays of less than 20 elements.

Comment: I answered the half of the question: no, Julia is not doing anything unusual here. That means that C++ is doing something unnecessarily slow. If you have an answer to the other half of the question (i.e. why C++ is slow), feel free to post it as well, or propose it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: There are a number of way to implement quicksort and in selection of the pivot -- that you hit on in your answer. There are different quicksorts altogether.stable / unstable, blended methods. If I recall GNU C qsort uses a combination of quicksort and mergesort depending on the number of chunks remaining. (as well as a few "magic" numbers. So likely it's more than just a what C++ does, but what 'that' C++ does.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/sort/doc/html/sort/single_thread/pdqsort/pdqsort_worst.html " In pdqsort we adopt a hybrid approach, (deterministically) shuffling some elements to break up patterns when we encounter a "bad" partition. If we encounter too many "bad" partitions we switch to heapsort." So I supect the problem is the patterns in the input are causing it to switch to the slower heapsort.

Comment: All the above comments assume that Boost's sort is slower than Julia. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925175/461597) I show that Boost is faster, whereas Julia and C++'s std::sort are similarly fast.

Answer (score 9):

## Summary

**TL;DR** Julia and C++'s `std::sort` are extremely close in performance. Boost's `pdqsort_branchless` is faster.

### Key Take-Aways

Methodology:

1. Only measure what is important. In your code you are also measuring set-up time to generate the vectors.
2. Be careful that the distribution of your test data is comparable to the distribution of your "production" data.
3. Make sure you compile with `-march=native -mtune=native` [ref](https://lemire.me/blog/2018/07/25/it-is-more-complicated-than-i-thought-mtune-march-in-gcc/)

Code:

- Boost's `pdqsort_branchless` is faster. The STL's `std::sort` and Julia's sort are reasonably close together in runtime performance.
- I also tested C's `qsort` which is slower. That's why I don't show it any further.
- I also used the *BenchmarkTools* Julia package to benchmark Julia's sort.

[image]

Plot explanation:

- I use [this](https://github.com/lakshayg/google_benchmark_plot) script for plotting.
- If labels are too small:

  - blue/fastest: boost's sort
  - green and red: `std::sort` and Julia.

## Benchmarking

### C++

On C++, use the [benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) library.

For your convenience, you can access it online at [Quick-Bench](https://quick-bench.com). Here is this code: https://quick-bench.com/q/CVu8y1fjwh19AHJH1iUCogxG6Pk

This lets you specify which part of your code you want to measure. It will also do the measuring and the statistics correctly.

Here's an example:

```cpp
static void Example(benchmark::State &state) {
  std::vector<int> data(1024);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);

  std::mt19937 mersenne_engine{1234};

  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    std::shuffle(data.begin(), data.end(), mersenne_engine);
    state.ResumeTiming();

    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Example);
```

*Google Benchmark* only measures code inside the `for (auto _ : state) {...}` block (the *timed block*). So, the code above avoids the pitfall of measuring setup time.

Before each run, the data is `shuffle`d.

### Julia

Use the `BenchmarkTools` library, where the benchmark is done like this:

```
Random.seed!(1234)
function make_vec(n)
    return Random.randperm(Int32(n));
end

@benchmark sort!(arr; alg=QuickSort) setup=(arr=make_vec(1024));
```

## Data Generation

We need to clarify the way you generate data.

As you discover, the algorithms work fastest on already sorted data and worse on reverse-sorted data.

In the end, the domain knowledge of where the benchmarked algorithm is run needs to be known. What is the shape of the data distribution?

### Random Data

First, let's just have uniformly distributed data in `[0, 10 000]`. Much better than testing on already sorted data.

I am using a fixed seed, so the data will be the same every time (for a given N). If you instantiate `mersenne_engine` with `rnd_device()`, you get a different seed every time, and thus differing data. Personally, I favor going with random but consistent data, to make the result less variable. Just keep it in mind for your later analysis.

Note that generating data between 0 and 10k will lead to many duplicates on inputs order of magnitudes greater than 10k.

### Shuffled Data

If you want don't want to have duplicates, then generate a vector with elements `[0, 1, 2, ..., N]` and then shuffle the data.

Here's how I'd do it:

```cpp
  // Create vector filled with 0..n
  std::vector<int> arr(n);
  std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
  std::shuffle(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), mersenne_engine);
}
```

Julia:

```
function make_vec(n)
    return Random.randperm(n);
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter for being the first with constructive criticism! The graph shows sorting 150k elements in 1e7 nanoseconds which is 10ms. Does that sound reasonable to you? -- Please provide more feedback, very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please put the entire code for the benchmark in a gist, a repo or something that can be easily used to reproduce your benchmarks?  Note also that the link to the plotting script points to a user profile on GitHub, it isn't very clear what you're talking about

Comment: The C++ code is using 32-but `int`s while the Julia code is using `Int64`. For a good comparison of the algorithm you should be using comparable types. I would suggest either using `std::vector<long long>` or using `Random.randperm(Int32(n))`

Comment: @Warren, good point. I'll run the benchmark again, this time both with Int32.